# Proposed Changes to a Topic should be deleted when the Topic is deleted

Tags: feature-request, documentation, documentation-topics

When I look at [the list of Proposed Changes on the JavaScript Language Documentation tag](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript?tab=proposedchanges&subtab=needreview&page=1), I see [a proposed change](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/57207) for a Topic, ECMAScript 2015, which has since been deleted.

There is nothing I can do on the page:

[image: The Proposed Changes section]

And yet it says it is "Awaiting approval".

If a change is proposed for a Topic, and the Topic is later deleted, can any Proposed Changes for that Topic be removed?